# Good ways of using CSS in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio

I searched a lot around here, and did not find anything spectacular about using CSS in Visual Studio. Many people talk around, but not specifically.

But I just want to know if there are some simple ways of managing CSS and collaborating it with ASP.NET pages and stuff in VS. Theming is out of discussion for today.

I would gladly accept advices on any tools, technologies and methodologies that can be used for making life easier.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest your read this great blog post from Scott Guthrie:

[**VS 2008 Web Designer and CSS Support**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/25/vs-2008-web-designer-and-css-support.aspx).

This video might also be of interest to you: [**learn about VWD’s CSS Editor, Builder, Manager, and IntelliSense.**](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/css)